# From UserControl to parent master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a weird scenario but this was how it was designed before me. Basically I have userControl, and there is a child.masterpage

in the userControl in the ascx file it contains the following

```
<div><%=_template%></div>
```

the child.masterpage inherits from a parent.masterpage, in the child.masterpage there is a call to the userControl

```
<asp:Content><ucc:UserControl></ucc>
```

the parent.masterpage has other fields in it and it has a .cs file with a c# function

```
public void passVal(string s)
```

Now what I want to do is to pass a value from the user control directly to the parent.masterpage function so that I can put it in the parent.masterpage literal I have created.

How can I achieve this (again, this is existing design and I cant turn things around) I am just adding a functionality.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="../common/main.master" %>
<%@ Register Src="UserControl.ascx" TagName="Ord" TagPrefix="uc" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
<div class="in"><uc:OrderReceipt ID="myord" runat="server" Visible="true"/>
 <div style="margin-bottom:30px;">
<a href="~/" id="HomeLink" runat="server" class="BackLink">Back to Home Page</a>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Page.Master` property to get a hold of the master page instance.

```
protected someEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   (Page.Master as ChildMaster).passVal("some string");
}
```

**More of an Answer:**

I was just reviewing your OP and realized something. The code that kept puzzling me was the user control.

> in the userControl in the ascx file it
>   contains the following

`<div><%=_template%></div>`

I haven't seen the code behind but my guess is that the user control is simply used to output dynamic HTML.  I bet if you looked at the code behind (.cs file) of the user control, you would find a variable called `_template`. It is a string variable that is pumped with html at run time.

Now, that doesn't answer your question but, if you didn't already know that ... it is good to know =P

Now, the next mystery is the one concerning your missing code behind file for the child master page.

My theory is that whoever made it did it with some error that would cause it not to automatically generate a code behind file. Or, they made it from scratch and just simply added it to the project but neglected to make a code behind as well.

I made a master page, then made another one called child. I am able to subclass it and here is what the markup and code behind look like.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" AutoEventWireup="true"   CodeFile="Child.master.cs" Inherits="Child" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>

public partial class Child : Master
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

In comparing the markup to yours, the key difference here is that mine explicitly mentions a `CodeFile` attribute.

Create a new cs file and following the naming convention. Then add the `CodeFile` and `Inherits` attributes to your child master page. This should wire everything up correctly and allow you to start adding methods and such to the child master page.

Let me know where you are at and we'll take it from there. GL

Comment: But you see how I have two masters in between? and I am in the UserControl, what should I put instead of MyMasterType (I am in the UserControl) ..

I can not see my method.. I tried Page.master.master as MasterPage

Comment: @user710502 ... Didn't you state that the childMaster is just a sub class of the parentMaster? If you have a public method in parentMaster ... it is available and exposed in childMaster because of inheritance.

Comment: Although I am in a UserControl (the child.master) does not have .cs file? bare with me i am a newbie in c#

Comment: How much more code, the code for one of the masters is hugeeee

Comment: @User710502 No, problem with the lack of understanding. I am pretty confident that there is a cs file that you just haven't seen. Go to your Solution Explorer and locate the item that represents the ChildMaster page. Right click on it and select "View Code". That will let you see the code behind page that every master page has.

Comment: See in my post (thats what it has there)

Comment: @User710502 Humor me and also post the child master page code exactly as it appears.

Comment: I think I am going to give up... The design of this thing is messed up (i did not build it) I am just trying to add the functionality

Comment: @user710502 I posted what I think to be the answer to your problem. GL